# Use recursion to count the number of nodes whose value field is between min and max, inclusive, from the "cur" node to the end of the list

Tags: java, recursion, nodes

My attempt at a solution, I know it is not right because the output for the program is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

I have an inner node class, each with value fields.This method should return the number of nodes that have value fields between ints min and max.

```
//---------------- countInRange( Node, int, int ) ------------------
private int countInRange( Node cur, int min, int max )
{
    if(cur == null)
        return 0;
    else {
        if(cur.value >= min && cur.value <= max)
            return (1+ countInRange(cur.next, min, max));
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Fixed your indentation.

Comment: It is just unnecessary overhead to use recursion here. Simply iterate over the list, it is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: That was my immediate reaction but this is a school question. What do you mean by overhead though?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only do the recursive call if the value is in range, otherwise you pretend that the remainder of the list has only one element in range.

You need to do the recursive call whether the value is in range or not. The only difference is whether you add 1 to the result or not before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

There are three paths through your recursive method:

1. The node is null, so it cannot be in range nor can it have any children. Returning 0 seems reasonable.
2. The node is not null, and it is in range. Returning 1 + recursion on the child node looks good.
3. The node is not null, and it is not in range. Rather than returning 1, I would return 0 + recursion on the child node.

The problem becomes clear if you rewrite and comment the code a bit (this code is functionally equivalent to yours but highlights the problem):

```
//---------------- countInRange( Node, int, int ) ------------------
private int countInRange( Node cur, int min, int max )
{

    if(cur == null) {
    // Node is null, end recursion
        return 0;
    }
    if(cur.value >= min && cur.value <= max) {
    // Node is in range, recurse and add 1
            return (1+ countInRange(cur.next, min, max));
        }
    } else { 
    // Node is not in range, recurse
        return 1; // ?!
    }
}
```